# javascript object literals -- formula

Tags: javascript, object, object-literal

I'm supposed to declare an object literal, accepting a parameter that gets the radius of the circle. Then returns the area of the circle. Not sure how to implement the formula A = PIr^2 This is what I have so far. Am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you have the `a` and `b` property. What is its purpose? Do you want something like this?

```js
var MathUtility = {
  getAreaOfCirlceForRadius: function(radius) {
    return Math.PI * radius * radius;
  },
  getRadiusOfCircleForArea: function(area) {
    return Math.sqrt(area / Math.PI);
  }
};

console.log(MathUtility.getRadiusOfCircleForArea(12.566370614359172));
console.log(MathUtility.getAreaOfCirlceForRadius(2));
```